# Scholarly 1.7.11 - No 'search_pubs_query' function

Tags: python, google-scholar

I tried to automize the literature review for my thesis. It seems like there is no 'search_pubs_query' function in scholarly anymore. Is that true and if so, is there another way to automate a literature review?

I deinstalled, installed, updated scholarly several times. I used other functions like 'scholarly.search_pubs' or 'scholarly.scholarly.search_author'. Nothing worked.